# Vue.js dynamic array in template not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I just started fiddling with VueJs and I tried a simple example where an array has values and use it in a template, it works just fine

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{operations.join(', ')}}
    </div>
</body>
<a href=""></a>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Understanding Hooks',
            operations: ['One', 'Two'],
        }
    })
</script>
```

However, when I tried to populate operations(array) dynamically page/browser becomes unresponsive (following is the code). Any inputs would be helpful.

```
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Undstanding Hooks',
            operations: ['One', 'Two'],
        },
        created: function() {
            console.log('=> ', this.operations)
            this.operations.push('CREATED : ');
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.operations.push('MOUNTED : ');
        },
        updated: function() {
            this.operations.push('UPDATED : ');
        },
        destroyed: function() {
            this.operations.push('DESTROYED : ');
        },
    })
</script>
```

Comment: try putting your script in an onload function, or maybe it's the typo in 'understanding' that's killing you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

`this.operations.push('UPDATED : ');` will make component `updated` hooks run infinite. Please try removing it.

And there is a best practice about immutable and reactive . Reference of `this.operations` is not changed.

You should use

`this.operations = [...this.operations, 'CREATED : ']`

instead of

`this.operations.push('CREATED : ');`

or

`this.operations = this.operations.concat(['CREATED :'])`

Comment: page just gets stuck not able to open console too ... it feels if I am actually missing some basic in vue ... so simple which is easy to miss

Comment: Can you comment out `this.operations.push('UPDATED : ');`? This will lead to infinite loop, then make your page hang

Comment: Yes with push in an array it's going in an infinite loop ... but not able to understand why? And if above is a solution (immutable update) then it should have fixed it but it could not it still failed.

Comment: Did you try removing `this.operations.push('UPDATED : ');`?

Comment: I completely removed it and then it started working where i only logged string